Stopping daemon/nginx to edit index.js file then restart daemon/nginx on EC2 Linux
I went through the process below to create a "Running Node.js API on Amazon Linux EC2 with Custom Domain and SSL Certificate"
https://resonant-cement-f3c.notion.site/Running-Node-js-API-on-Amazon-Linux-EC2-with-Custom-Domain-and-SSL-Certificate-f27601f25a5f4ae4a03a79e7d058766d
This works great except I cannot figure out how to stop the processes running in Step 7 and 8 below if I want to make changes/edit my index.js file and then restart the processes below in Step 7 and 8
Step 7. Configure the application to start automatically
Run sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/<daemon_name>.service to create a daemon service.
Copy and paste this inside the editor.
[Unit]
Description=Example of Node.js API running on Amazon Linux

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/wwwroot/<application-name>
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node index.js
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
SyslogIdentifier=<application-name>
Environment=NODE_PORT=3000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Use ctrl + o to write, and ctrl + x to exit.
Start the daemon service.
sudo systemctl enable <daemon_name>
sudo systemctl start <daemon_name>
sudo systemctl status <daemon_name>
​
Step 8. Update Nginx configuration to point to Node.js application

Refer to Install Nginx and configure it as a reverse proxy server for more details.
Run whereis nginx to discover where the program is installed.
Open the Nginx configuration file in the nano editor. Run the below command.
sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
​
Use the below configuration to update the Nginx config file.
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name _;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

Restart the nginx service and verify.
sudo systemctl restart nginx

systemctl restart [whatever deamon name you picked]

@Evert unfortunately this did not work...   the old version of index.js was still running.  When I do cat index.js it does show the code of the new file

'did not work' is not a useful reply. Share exactly what you did and what the result was.
